# Eclipselink: Custom implementation for CRUD operations

Tags: orm, jpa, eclipselink

Is it possible to provide a custom java methods for the basic CRUD operations using Eclipselink? So, i want java method InsertObjectA to run whenever em.persist is called on ObjectA and so on for other basic operations.

EclipseLink documentation says that I can create custom implementation by [configuring the relational descriptor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Configuring_a_Relational_Descriptor_%28ELUG%29). However, this requires me to specify the SQL String or use Stored procedures/functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @PrePersist annotation on the method within the Entity you want to be called when the persist operation is applied to the Entity.  If you want all of the operations to call the same method you can simply add the other event annotations (@PreUpdate, @PreMerge, etc) to the same method.